# How can I send header message in Java by using org.apache.axis.client.Stub and java.rmi.Remote?

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl and this wsdl has a request message like this, in SOAPUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:service="www.xxxxx.xx">
<soapenv:Header>
<service:SessionInfo>
<service:UserPassword>?</service:UserPassword>
</service:SessionInfo></soapenv:Header> 
<soapenv:Body>
<service:Method1>
<!--Optional:-->
<service:Arguments>
<service:Parameter1>?</service:Parameter1>
<service:Parameter2>?</service:Parameter2>
<!--Optional:-->
<service:Parameter3>?</service:Parameter3>
<!--Optional:-->
<service:Parameter4>?</service:Parameter4>
</service:Arguments>
</service:Method1></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am having problem while sending header message of this wsdl in Java. I sent the request message in C# and SOAPUI successfully. After importing wsdl in Java I could not access the header part of this request although I was able to access in SOAPUI and C#. I can only access body part of this wsdl in Java but I cannot access soapenv:Header part in Java. Is there a solution for this problem by using org.apache.axis.client.Stub and java.rmi.Remote?
How can I add header? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `custom headers` as below:

```
 MessageContext responseMessageContext =  
           MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext().getOperationContext().getMessageContext(  
                   WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_OUT_VALUE);  
    List headers = new ArrayList();  
    headers.add(new Header(HTTPConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING, "identity"));  
    responseMessageContext.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, headers);
```

or else check this way from the link [here](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/02/adding-custom-http-headers-via-axis2.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need a solution without using axis2 library. Is there any other library for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

With `org.apache.axis.axis` library, just cast the service port to `org.apache.axis.client.Stub`

- to add a specific header :

  ```java
  // Instanciate the service
  ExampleServices Service service = new ExampleServicesServiceLocator();
  ExampleServices port = service.getExampleServicesServicePort();

  // Cast the port to Stub
  Stub stub = (Stub)port;

  // Set header
  stub.setHeader(/* SOAPHeaderElement header */);
  ```